# LibVLC Android: Video not scaling to VLCVideoLayout size

Tags: android, libvlc

I'm having a problem with the video output on a VLCVideoLayout.

Video plays fine, however it plays with its original size instead of fitting inside of the VLCVideoLayout.

Here's what I already attempted but failed:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams videoParams = videoLayout.getLayoutParams();
mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout().setWindowSize(videoParams.width, videoParams.height);
```

Here's part of my layout:

```
<org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout
android:id="@+id/player"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"/>
```

I'm using version 3.2.6

```
implementation 'org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.2.6'
```

The end result it's the crop of center part of the video (or a zoom on the center?).

This is a picture with the problem.
The white part is the rest of the layout, on the center i have the VLCVideoLayout.
The video has a lot more than what the VLCVideoLayout is showing.
[image: Sample of the problem]

Anybody can help?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the entire Layout? Have you tried `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"`?

Comment: Hi, the entire layout has other linearlayouts (i don't think that's where the problem is, there's no connection between them and the vlc player) and yes, I already tried wrapping the player inside a linearlayout and using match_parent on the player, no success

Comment: What color do you see when you add `android:background="#FFFF0000"`to `org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout` and `android:background="#FF00FF00"` to its parent element?

Comment: I don't see the background color, i see the cropped video playing

Comment: Maybe with `ViewGroup.LayoutParams videoParams = videoLayout.getLayoutParams();` you are getting those `200dp x 120dp` you're setting in the XML, but in that case you should be seeing a large green area around the video as that VLCVideoLayout would only be `200dp x 120dp` big. If you get the LayoutParams of the parent element and pass those values into `getVLCVout().setWindowSize()`, would that help?

Comment: Done that way too, still the same problem. The `getVLCVout().setWindowSize(parent.width, parent.height)` part seems to be ignored, even with constant values. Maybe i need to refresh something? There's very little documentation online

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49449718/277267 ? Specifically the `.attachCallback(this)` line.

Comment: Problem solved! In the code I do absolutely nothing to change the size, I just changed library from 3.2.6 to 3.3.0-eap10. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question.  I was disillusioned when I first saw that there were no answer.  I was using 3.1.12 and same problem, updated to 3.3.9 and all good.